# Localization in Arabic

Tags: localization, autolayout

I am currently working on Localization. I have my app in English and Arabic. When I change the Language to Arabic all object goes to right, but there are few objects that i want them to be in left. Could please tell how to disable that function on a specific object?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the **semanticContentAttribute** property for the particular view to **forceLeftToRight**

```
someView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
```

You can find more about it [semanticContentAttribute](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622461-semanticcontentattribute) in apple docs